# Can I use iPhone or ipad device as a server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, webserver

Can I use iPhone or iPad device as a server without jail breaking it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uPnP server?

Even you have unlimited data plan, or connected to Wi-Fi, it is unwise to make the device as a server. It is not designed to be a server.

But you can still implement the logic of uPnP and give out your device IP for other people to connect to your device. However, intense use of network will cause battery draining fast. You should note that.